# Data Access in BusinessObjects through Active Directory Groups

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I have different Active Directory groups and one BO universe.
Different active directory groups should have different restricted access on data in the universe.
How can I implement that? (unfortunately I did not found corresponding tutorial or documentation on the net.)
If there are more than one ways to implement data access, what is the best practice?
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of BO?  If BI4, are you using IDT or UDT?  Are you looking for row-level security (in which all users see all universe objects, but certain rows are filtered out by group), or column-level (in which the objects in the universe are visible to only certain groups)?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, Joe. I am using BO 4, IDT. I am still waiting for the feedback regarding the other questions, and will get back to you wenn I revive it. Meanwhile, is there some youtube tutorial or documentation I can lookup?

Comment: The IDT User Guide is [here](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41sp1_info_design_tool_en.pdf).  Check sections 17.4 and 17.5 for information on applying security restrictions.

Comment: Hi @Joe - just got the feedback: row-level security should be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main ways to implement row-level security in a universe.  One is via a Security Profile; the other is via `@variable('BOUSER')`.

If the security is to be applied at a *group* level (that is, all members of a group should have the same condition applied), then a *Security Profile* is appropriate.  This is covered in Chapter 17 of the [IDT User Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41sp1_info_design_tool_en.pdf).  At a high level, the steps are:

- From IDT, launch the Security Editor
- Select the universe, and create either a *Data Security Profile* or a *Business Security Profile* (read the docs for the differences between the two, but one is that with the DSP, you will write a WHERE condition; with the BSP, you select objects and define a condition)
- Once the Security Profile is created, select the group or groups that it should apply to
- Repeat the above for each group that should have a restriction applied

The other method for applying row-level security is only applicable when the data source includes a table that has a mapping of BO user IDs to the values that they may have access to.  For example, let's say you have a security table in your data source that looks like this:

```
user_id  region
-------  ------
U123     NE
U123     SE
U321     W
```

and your fact table looks like:

```
pk   region   value
__   ______   _____
 1       NE       3
 2        W       4
```

You can apply security such that user U123 only sees the "NE" row, and user U321 only sees the "W" row.  You would join the two tables on region (`security.region=fact.region`), then create a new mandatory filter on `security.user_id=@variable('BOUSER')`.  This will force the filter to be applied to all queries.

Note that both of the above methods work by adding conditions to the query's WHERE condition.  If your users have permission to view and edit the query's SQL, they will be above to override the filtering logic.  To ensure security, users should be denied this right.

Comment: one more question - in CMC, do I have to create a user group and then add members in that group OR can I simply create Active Directory group with certain users and thenassign this AD Group to specific Data Security Profile? Which option is better?

Comment: Mapping the AD group is must easier -- see the "Authentication" section in the CMC.